# *ngFor does not display data from API in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display the name and age from API JSON but nothing is displaying. I've copied the array of objects of data below from the console. I've read through some other posts and tried some key/value solutions and cannot resolve.

BirthdayService to retrieve celebrity birthdays from API :

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class BirthdayService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getBirthdays() {
    return this.http.get(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://celebritybucks.com/developers/birthdays/JSON`
    );
  }
}
```

component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { BirthdayService } from "../services/birthday.service";

@Pipe({ name: "values" })
@Component({
  selector: "app-api-birthday",
  templateUrl: "./api-birthday.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./api-birthday.component.css"],
})
@Injectable()
export class ApiBirthdayComponent implements OnInit {
  articles;

  constructor(private apiService: BirthdayService) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getBirthdays().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.articles = data["articles"];
    });
  }
}
```

Html :

```
  <ul>
  <div *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <h2>{{ article.name }}</h2>

    <p>
      {{ article.age }}
    </p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Console - console.log() :

```
{Birthdays: Array(19)}
Birthdays: Array(19)
0: {celebId: "3714", name: "Jane Lynch", dob: "1960-07-14", havePic: "1", twitter: "", …}
1: {celebId: "3540", name: "Jackie Earle Haley", dob: "1961-07-14", havePic: "1", twitter: "", …}
2: {celebId: "5727", name: "Matthew Fox", dob: "1966-07-14", havePic: "1", twitter: "", …}
3: {celebId: "7534", name: "Scott Porter", dob: "1979-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
4: {celebId: "1753", name: "Dale Robertson", dob: "1923-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
5: {celebId: "2167", name: "Donald Meek", dob: "1878-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
6: {celebId: "2195", name: "Doris Nolan", dob: "1916-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
7: {celebId: "2957", name: "George Tobias", dob: "1901-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
8: {celebId: "3195", name: "Harry Dean Stanton", dob: "1926-07-14", havePic: "1", twitter: "", …}
9: {celebId: "3821", name: "Jean Dixon", dob: "1896-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
10: {celebId: "5153", name: "Lino Ventura", dob: "1919-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
11: {celebId: "6189", name: "Nancy Olson", dob: "1928-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
12: {celebId: "6324", name: "Nina Siemaszko", dob: "1970-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
13: {celebId: "6767", name: "Polly Bergen", dob: "1930-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
14: {celebId: "7476", name: "Sara Canning", dob: "1987-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
15: {celebId: "7740", name: "Stan Shaw", dob: "1952-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
16: {celebId: "1", name: "Val Avery", dob: "1924-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
17: {celebId: "93", name: "Vincent Pastore", dob: "1946-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
18: {celebId: "8506", name: "Zita Johann", dob: "1904-07-14", havePic: "0", twitter: "", …}
length: 19
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Based on your console log, it looks like it should be `this.articles = data.Birthdays`. And you will need to change `(data: any[])` to either just `data` or `data: any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have 3 decorators, `@Pipe`, `@Component`, and `@Injectable`?  You are creating a component, you should only have `@Component`.

I made a stackblitz with your code (and a mock of the service), and while this is Angular 10, not 8, Having all three decorators throws an error.  Removing the `@Pipe` makes it work, but you should also remove the `@Injectable` as well.

See example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4cbdfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If you uncomment the `@Pipe` in the stackblitz, Angular will error.

Also, like the user Chris commented, your data type from `getBirthdays` is incorrect, if it has a property `articles` which is an array, then the whole object is not an array.

Here is the full component from stackblitz incase it goes away

```js
import { Component, VERSION, Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable , of} from 'rxjs';

// uncommenting the @Pipe will break the component, this is angular 10 though, so the error might be silent in v8
// @Pipe({name: 'values'})
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
// @Injectable() // Why do you have this here?
export class AppComponent  {

  articles;

  async ngOnInit() {
    // this was typed wrong, its not an array if it has a property 'articles'
    // I also didn't want to create a new service so I just mocked it 
    this.getBirthdays().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.articles = data["articles"];
    });
  }

  // mock of your service call
  getBirthdays(): Observable<any> {
    return of(
      {articles: 
      [
        {name : 'test 1', age: 10},
        {name : 'test 2', age: 8},
        {name : 'test 3', age: 15},
        {name : 'test 4', age: 22},
      ]}
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all! The corrections posted by @cjd82187 solved it!!

Comment: Glad to help!  I find it best to use the Angular CLI when creating new components/services/etc because it will create the classes and decorators correctly.  It looks like you may have copied and pasted some stuff from other files and didn't know what was required/what wasn't which leads to odd errors like this over time.